# IE equivalent to -webkit-appearance?

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

I wouldn't ask this question if I could find any information on this anywhere. I have checked w3schools, this site, and google. Nothing.

So, is there a css -ms equivalent to -webkit-appearance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply Googling "*CSS appearance MDN*" we get

```
Feature         Chrome   Edge         Firefox (Gecko)    Internet Explorer  Opera   Safari (WebKit)  
Basic support   1.0      (Yes)  1.0   (1.7 or earlier)   No support         ?       3.0
                -webkit               -moz[1]                                       -webkit
```

You can easily conclude that there is no even basic support in Internet Explorer for such property.

Considering that IE has been outdated by Edge, there is no reason to believe that there *appearance* will ever be supported.

Also [*appearance* has been dropped](https://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui#dropped-css3-features), as today, from future CSS specifications.

Comment: Thanks. I googled -webkit, which returned 0 results.

Comment: @Demeter Beware when googling words with hyphens (-), Google consider them operators. Put the words in quotes (e.g. "-webkit")