# -webkit-appearance equivalent in CSS3 and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've been looking for a good alternative for `appearance:none` for sometime. I need to have a checkbox which is required to look different.

Also I got to know that CSS3 would be dropping `appearance`, although major browsers support it now. So, what would be the better alternative for it If I intend to keep the checkbox and not to use button?

- [IE equivalent to -webkit-appearance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313177/ie-equivalent-to-webkit-appearance)
- [MSDN | -webkit-appearance property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793580(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [css3 appearance property for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088925/css3-appearance-property-for-ie)
- [CSS Appearance](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this**

```css
input[type="checkbox"].novisible {
    display: none;
}
.checkboxCl {
  border:1px solid #333;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display:block;
}
input[type="checkbox"].novisible:checked + label {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/L/I/b/q/o/green-check-mark-hi.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
   <input type="checkbox" class="novisible" id="checkBox">
   <label for="checkBox" class="checkboxCl"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following. This is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465739.aspx) to the documentation.

```
your selector::-ms-check {
your styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I found out an alternate method for `appearance` property.

Easiest of all is making use of `:after` and `:before` and hiding the applied object.

Also, it is important to note that IE won't add any content if the property is a checkbox/radio button. Make sure to add a label and for that add `:after` or `:before`.